# Newline is not '\n'

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, line-breaks

I have a text file which was created by Matlab (I don't have the source code), and was in the form:

```
a   b   c   d

e   f   g   h
```

I used

```
sed -i '' $'s/\t/\/g' filename
```

to replace all the tabs with commas and ended up have a file that looks like this:

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
```

then, I tried to remove all the line breaks using

```
tr '\n' ' ' < filename
```

It gave me only the last line, But when I manually edited the text file by placing the pointer to the end of the line and then pressing "del" and "enter" and re-ran the code it worked fine.
So, the newline in the text file is probably not symbolized by \n, what other chars are there to symbolize line breaks?

P.S If I run the tr line on the file before I remove the tabs I get an empty output.

Thank you.

Comment: MATLAB might be using Windows style line breaks.  Try '\r\n'

Comment: Could you clarify your desired output? Should there be commas between `d` and `e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your newlines are `\r\n` (Windows-style ones). One option would be to remove them first using this command:

```
tr -s '\r\n' ' ' < file
```

The `-s` switch means each sequence of characters present in the input is only replaced by a single space. Thanks to [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) for pointing this out.

Guessing your intention slightly, you may want to use something like this, to replace all spaces including line breaks with commas:

```
tr -s '[:space:]' ',' < file
```

You could then pipe this to `sed` to remove the trailing comma if you wanted.